# horizontal spacing of subplots with equal aspect ratio

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'm trying to draw two rows with three columns of pcolormesh plots and a combined colorbar for all plots. So far it seems to work. However, I'm sure I'm not using the most elegant way...
The only problem I have, is that I can't decrease the horizontal spacing any further. The following line should set the horizontal spacing to zero:

```
fig.subplots_adjust(left=0.05, right=0.98, top=0.93, bottom=0.00, wspace=0, hspace=0.03)
```

But this does not work in conjunction with

```
ax.set_aspect('equal')
```

I've attached a small code snippet that creates the following figure:
[Example figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hg85i.png)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec

rows = 2
columns = 3

fig = plt.figure()
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(rows+1, columns)

lines = []

x = np.linspace(1,10,100)
y = x
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
Z = np.random.rand(100,100)

lines = []
for i in range(rows):
    lines.append([])
    for j in range(columns):
        ax = fig.add_subplot(gs[i, j])

        line = ax.pcolormesh(X, Y, Z, cmap=plt.cm.Reds)
        lines[i].append(line)

        ax.set_aspect('equal')

        for tick in ax.get_xticklabels():
            tick.set_rotation(45)

        if i!=rows-1:
            ax.set_xticklabels([])
        if j!=0:
            ax.set_yticklabels([])
        #title
        props = dict(boxstyle='round', facecolor='white', alpha=0.7)
        ax.text(0.05, 0.95, "plot (%i, %i)" % (i,j), transform=ax.transAxes, fontsize=5,
                verticalalignment='top', bbox=props)
        ax.tick_params(labelsize=7)

cb_ax = fig.add_subplot(gs[-1,:])
cb_ax.set_aspect(0.05)

cbar = fig.colorbar(lines[0][0], cax=cb_ax, orientation='horizontal')
cb_ax.tick_params(labelsize=7)

fig.subplots_adjust(left=0.05, right=0.98, top=0.93, bottom=0.00, wspace=0, hspace=0.03)
#fig.tight_layout()
fig.text(0.5, 0.2, "x axis", ha='center', va='center')
fig.text(0.5, 0.97, "overall title", ha='center', va='center')
fig.text(0.02, 0.5, "y axis", ha='center', va='center', rotation='vertical')
fig.text(0.5, 0.02, "quantity [unit]", ha='center', va='center',)
plt.savefig("test.png", dpi=600)
```

Comment: Why do you use `ax.set_aspect('equal')` when the things are working your way without using it? Just comment it out and use `fig.subplots_adjust(left=0.05, right=0.98, top=0.93, bottom=0.00, wspace=0.05, hspace=0.05)` to get a nicely spaced plot. Understanding why they don't go hand in hand is another issue which is unclear to me yet

Comment: @Bazingaa because I need the plots to have an equal aspect ratio. If I remove `ax.set_aspect('equal')` the plots become rectangles which is unacceptable for the type of data I'm plotting.

Comment: There is one constraint too much and equal aspect takes precendence over `wspace`. Or in other words `wspace` denotes the *minimal* spacing, not the actual spacing. Maybe you can describe a bit more how you would like the plot to look like instead? Would you like to have a narrower figure? Would you like to have more white space to the left and right of the grid? You could also make the colorbar take less space in height or use `ax.set_aspect('equal', adjustable="datalim")`.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I want the individual plots to be squares and the width of the whole figure to be as small as possible. I basically want the figure that I have now but without the white spaces in horizontal direction. `ax.set_aspect('equal', adjustable="datalim")` appears to keep the whitespaces but draws the axes around the whitespaces. However, I want to get rid of the whitespaces in horizontal direction since they are essentially wasted space for my application.

Comment: So what about `plt.figure(figsize=(5,4.8))`?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest works perfectly, thanks